# Group by similar strings in SAS within a column

Tags: sas

I have the following table:

```
Name
----
John Smith
John Smth
Jane Lee
Jane Line
Timothy Brown
Timmothy Brown
Agnes James
Aaron James
```

Using SAS, how can I group these strings on a large scale to identify those that are similar, so that I can get this table:

```
Name
----
John Smith
John Smth
Timothy Brown
Timmothy Brown
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways in SAS to perform comparisons of strings.  A simple example is using `SOUNDEX` to find two strings that *sound* alike.

```
data have;
input Name $char20.;
datalines;
John Smith
John Smth
Jane Lee
Jane Line
Timothy Brown
Timmothy Brown
Agnes James
Aaron James
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    A.name
  , B.name as name2
  , soundex(A.name) as sxname
  , soundex(B.name) as sxname2
  from have a
  cross join 
  have b
  where a.name lt b.name
  having sxname = sxname2
  ;
```

Other techniques would use a matching criterion based on a metric such as  Levenshtein edit distance, which can be computed with `COMPLEV`.  You can also learn more about `SPEDIS`.

Searching up How to perform a fuzzy match using SAS functions and you will get plenty to chew on.  Keep an eye out for papers by Charles Patridge